# Can I name final jar file with version included after building an artifact?

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I use maven and I'm getting my jar from building an artifact, and I'm in a need of jar file to looking like "app-1.0.0.jar"

how can I do this?

thank you!

Comment: Due to a [moderator/volunteer strike](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderator-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-and?r=Saves_AllUserSaves) I will not be performing any content curation on this question.

Comment: How do you assemble your jar? The answer depends on plugin that you use. Anyway, probably you have to specify ${project.name}-${project.version}.jar as an output artefact file name

Answer (score 0):

The version of the artifact has a dedicated element in the pom.xml file. In your case use this:

```
<artifactId>app</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0.0</version>
```